# HTML static side navbar

Tags: html, css, navigation, sidebar

How can I fix my static right navigation bar? I'm sorry if this is a general question. Basically, I'm trying to go with a two-columned style site with a header and footer. The header, footer, and layout are all completed, however, I'm having difficulty making the sidebar static. Here's my CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: #00FE52;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  color: #00FE52;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida        Typewriter', monospace;
  font-size: 28px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  padding-top: 80px;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida  Typewriter', monospace;
}
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding: 80%;
  float: left;
  height: (100% - 80px);
  width: 20%;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #00FE52;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida   Typewriter', monospace;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<div id="header" data-position="fixed">
  <p>Traxitor Development</p>
</div>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content">
  <p>This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This
    should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should
    show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show
    up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up
    in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in
    on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on the left side. This should show up in on
    the left side.</p>




</div>

<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div id="navbar">
  <p>This should show up on the right side</p>



</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <p>Traxitor Development - Copyright © 2016 - Theme created by <a href="https://twitter.com/9fiftyfive" style="color:#00FE52;text-decoration:none;">@9fiftyfive</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 80%;
    align: left;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:20px;
    height: (100% - 80px);
    width: 20%;
     font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, 'Lucida Sans Typewriter', 'Lucida Typewriter', monospace;
    }
```

**[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/qhw55wso/1/)**

Comment: Thanks! I do want to know, however, why the text in the "content" class is bolder than the text in the "navbar" class (https://traxitor.com). Thanks!

Comment: I have added font-size:20px; in navbar css just to highlight text...You can remove font-size from your actual code. Otherwise content and navbar text are of same size, weight, font-family....